# Spring test : Missing servlet context

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, servlets

I am writing test-cases for Spring, but having a really hard time getting it up and running to load all spring beans. I am getting `Missing Servlet Context error` all the time. I have given paths for context, so I expected, that the files would be automatically loaded, but seems to me that's not the case.

TestingController :

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath*:../../main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml",
        "classpath*:../../main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml", "classpath*:../../main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/security-applicationContext.xml"})
@Ignore
@ComponentScan("com.tooltank.spring")
public class TestingController {

    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("servlet-context.xml","root-context.xml","security-applicationContext.xml");

    @Autowired
    protected PersonService personService = (PersonService) context.getBean("personService");

    @Autowired
    protected GroupAccountService groupAccountService = (GroupAccountService) context.getBean("groupAccountService");

    @Autowired
    protected GroupCanvasService groupCanvasService = (GroupCanvasService) context.getBean("groupCanvasService");

    @Autowired
    protected GroupSectionService groupSectionService = (GroupSectionService) context.getBean("groupSectionService");

    @Autowired
    protected GroupNotesService groupNotesService = (GroupNotesService) context.getBean("groupNotesService");

    @Autowired
    protected GroupMembersService groupMembersService = (GroupMembersService) context.getBean("groupMembersService");

    @Qualifier("authenticationManager")
    protected AuthenticationManager am;

    @After
    public void clear() {
        SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
    }

    protected void login(String name, String password) {
        Authentication auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(name, password);
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(am.authenticate(auth));
    }

}
```

I have copied the 3 xml files and added them in resources so I can directly access them.

mvn test output :

```
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 2.061 sec <<< FAILURE! - in tests.AllTests
runTests(tests.AllTests)  Time elapsed: 0.007 sec  <<< ERROR!
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'bayeuxInitializer': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private javax.servlet.ServletContext com.tooltank.spring.chat.BayeuxInitializer.servletContext; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.servlet.ServletContext] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1380)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1126)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1021)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:545)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1218)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)

Results :

Tests in error: 
  AllTests.<init>:9->TestingController.<init>:26 » BeanCreation Error creating b...

Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 10.740 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-11-27T17:01:26+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 53M/507M
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong? Thank you.

*Update*

Updated testing controller :

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath*:../../main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml",
        "classpath*:../../main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml", "classpath*:../../main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/security-applicationContext.xml"})
@Ignore
@ComponentScan("com.tooltank.spring")
@WebAppConfiguration
public class TestingController {

 @Autowired
    protected PersonService personService;

    @Autowired
    protected GroupAccountService groupAccountService;
// othre autowired
}
```

Error log :

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.tooltank.spring.service.PersonService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1380)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1126)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1021)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:545)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
```

PersonServiceImpl :

```
@Service(value = "personService")
@Transactional
public class PersonServiceImpl implements PersonService {

    private final PersonDAO personDAO;

   @Autowired
    public PersonServiceImpl(PersonDAO personDAO) {
        this.personDAO = personDAO;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why on earth are you creating your own context (that is already done by the test framework). If you want a web based test add `@WebAppConfiguration` to your test (as explained [in the reference guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/testing.html#webappconfiguration))

Comment: @M.Deinum : I have removed the ApplicationContext part and added the WebAppConfiguration without the XML paths as shown in the guide. I get autowiring error. Can you please check updated post. Adding PersonServiceImpl details.

Comment: Adding `@ComponentScan` on a test will do nothing. You need to load all your configuration files.

Comment: @M.Deinum : Those are the only 3 configuration files I have which are loaded with ContextConfiguration, anything else I am missing? Thank you.

Comment: @M.Deinum : Any ideas sir? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So,

THe issue was with websockets libraries from cometd. As soon as we commented out websocket functionality, tests started working. These are the 2 libraries we commented.

```
<dependency>
                  <groupId>org.cometd.java</groupId>
                  <artifactId>cometd-java-websocket-javax-server</artifactId>
                  <version>3.1.2</version>
              </dependency>
              <dependency>
                  <groupId>javax.websocket</groupId>
                  <artifactId>javax.websocket-api</artifactId>
              </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.cometd.java</groupId>
            <artifactId>cometd-java-websocket-common-server</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Autowired
private ApplicationContext context;
```

Try this, it should work,

Comment: This didnt help. Thank you.